# Assigning reference returned from method to variable

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, operator-overloading

```
class A{
/.../
};

class B{
  public:
    A& foo()
    {
       A *bar = new A;
       return *bar;
     }
};

int main()
{
   A varA;
   B varB;
   varA = varB.foo();
   return 0;
}
```

What will happen when this line is executed `varA = varB.foo()` ? Will (after copy/move assignment operator function call) destructor for object created in foo be called?

Comment: _"What will happen when this line is executed `varA = varB.foo()`"_ A memory leak

Comment: `foo()` returns a reference to an object on the heap. `varA` is copy-assigned from that object, which is then leaked.

Comment: No, the destructor of the object created with `new` won't be called. Head over to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new and use it as a starting point for learning more about the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor will not be called, the allocated object will leak.

Comment: Unless `A`'s copy constructor does something weird.